# Grpc - send message from one client to another client that is connected to the same server

Tags: c#, server, client, message, grpc

Is it possible to send message from one client to another client that is connected to the same server?

I want send data from one client to server Then send to specific client. I think I need to get client ID but I dont know how to get this id and  how  to send this message to that client from server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a sample here. This is a chat server-client application. Multiple clients can connect to the server. When a client writes a message, the server simply broadcasts it for all clients who are receiving server stream RPC.

https://github.com/cactuaroid/GrpcWpfSample

See these server side implementation. When a client calls `Subscribe()`, it awaits `m_chatService.Added` event. When a client calls `Write()`, it raises the event and event args `ChatLog` is written on `responseStream`.

https://github.com/cactuaroid/GrpcWpfSample/blob/f6e8c4b2493c23cdcbaffeca29b5bb6705fbe95c/GrpcWpfSample.Server/Grpc/ChatServiceGrpcServer.cs
https://github.com/cactuaroid/GrpcWpfSample/blob/f6e8c4b2493c23cdcbaffeca29b5bb6705fbe95c/GrpcWpfSample.Server/Model/ChatService.cs

You can add your logic such as specifying channel name to subscribe/write, or define OpenChannel(string password) to be called by client at the first time so that server can bind the client IP address to the channel, whatever as you like.

Comment: I found I answered almost same question before... just FYI https://stackoverflow.com/a/52939764/3295402

Answer (score 1):

There's no special gRPC feature that would allow you to do this (all RPC are between a server and a client, there's no "broadcast" or "selective broadcast" feature to reach out to other clients connected to the same server.

The logic you want is something that can definitely be implemented and but details of such solution depend on your need. A naive approach that might work is e.g. this:

- each client opens a bidi-streaming call to the server
- server keeps a directory of connected clients
- once server receives a message from a client, it selects which client it should forward to based on the directory.
- server forwards the message to a client.

Needless to say this setup feels a bit complicated (you're basically implementing your own network protocol on top of gRPC), so even though it might be just the right thing for you to do, it would make sense to think about how to simplify the protocol so that you can use features directly supported by gRPC.

Comment: Thanks Jan. The problem is that I dont know how to keeps a directory of connected clients.

Comment: This is what you could do: as soon as each client starts, it creates a new long-lived streaming RPC, which will act as a registration with the server (as long as that RPC hasn't finished, server will keep client's  identity in the "directory". Depending on your security needs, you can use different values as "client identity". The simplest once is ServerCallContext.Peer (client's address and port)).