# Streaming communication client - server - secound client

Tags: c#, client, client-server, grpc, proto

https://zapodaj.net/b4ffc49a72077.png.html

I want make connection like on photo. In my rly program I have more clients B, and list which send from server to client A is every object from clients B.
Int in dictionary is ip for which client B send list.

Is it imposible to create it in Grpc?

Maybe someone have basic example how create connection like this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57720749/grpc-send-message-from-one-client-to-another-client-that-is-connected-to-the-s/57821567#57821567 seems to be a very similar discussion.

Comment: thanks for this message. However, I need this solution, i am tring use event to send messege from server to secound clinet. Which wait in loop while with sleep(10). I dont know this is good solution, but i dont have idea for better.