# ASP.NET Core | How to make local network gRPC clients pool

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, connection-pooling, grpc

I'm trying to build a system consisting of 1 main server and at least 2 gRPC services (hosted using HTTP.Sys) that could both be clients to the main server and accept connections from the main server hereinafter referred to as the **"Workers"**. Every element of the system is inside a local network. A worker once started connects to the main server and the main server should add the connection in the pool, where the client worker could be accessed later to make a gRPC call. Example of how I'm expecting this to work below

```
public class MainServer : MainServer.MainServerGrpcBase
{
    public List<GrpcChannel> ChannelPool { get; set; }
    public MainServer()
    {
        ChannelPool = new List<GrpcChannel>();
    }

    public override async Task<Confirmation> Connect(ConnectionRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        ChannelPool.Add(context.Channel);
        return new Confirmation { Success = true; }
    }

    // Having a channel pool allows me using methods like this.
    public void BroadcastMessage(string message)
    {
        foreach(var channel in ChannelPool)
        {
            var client = new Worker.WorkerClient(channel);
            client.SendMessage(message);
        }
    }
}
```

**What I have tried:**

- Determining worker IP on client-side and sending it to main server, then creating a channel using `GrpcChannel.FromAddress(...)` as a result I discovered that I can't acquire appropriate worker address to create a channel from.
- Creating a channel from `ServerCallContext.Peer`, that property returns strange IPv6 address not suitable for creating a channel.

**TLDR;** I need a gRPC server able to store client gRPC services for further use, like broadcasting messages.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, you tried to send messages from a server to the client, after the request from the client to the server had already been processed. This is not possible because HTTP allows sending requests from a client to a server and not the other way around. Since gRPC is using HTTP/2, you need to use another approach to solve your problem.

Consider creating a subscription service. It's a server-streaming service where you could send one message from the client to the server and then the server could send a stream of response messages when needed. Check out this post for more info:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52939764/9742876